# VS 2015 Nuget not putting .js files into lib folder

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget-package

I'm running vs 2015, I have installed the Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax package.  It installs just fine without any errors but I can't find anywhere in my project the jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax.js file.  I also can't install it using bower because bower doesn't find any microsoft packges.  Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: Did you expand the Scripts folder?

Comment: This is an asp net core project, so I have a wwwroot, with css,images,js and lib.  The lib folder is where both nuguet and bower put their files, but for some reason Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax isnt working.

Answer (score 1):

There is a global packages folder for project.json projects which should be available in %UserProfile%\.nuget\packages (Windows). I was able to find it in mine. However, I believe this package should be installed using Bower instead.